# Undefined control sequence. $\Deltaup in the template of Proceedings of the Royal Society A (PRSA)

Tags: templates

In the template of Proceedings of the Royal Society A, I want to use the command "\Deltaup", however, compiling the file, I encounter the following error: "Undefined control sequence. $\Deltaup". I would like to know how can I resolve this problem. Thank you!
The template starts as follows:

\documentclass[]{rsos}%%%%where rsos is the template name

%%%% *** Do not adjust lengths that control margins, column widths, etc. ***
\usepackage{upgreek}

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  The default `\Delta` is upright, as are all uppercase Greek letters.  The package `upgreek` also makes the lowercase letters upright.

Comment: Thank you BarBara. However, what you mentioned is not the case for me. I mean in the template I mentioned, \Delta does not correspond to the upright capital Delta which I need, but it produces italic capital Delta. In addition, the package upgreek does not fix this problem. I used \Deltaup, but it causes the error I mentioned in my question. I would like to know if there is any trick to resolve this problem and to be able to produce the upright capital \Delta. Thank you.

Comment: It's not easy to find the document class!  (But I did.)  It contains an option `CapsGreek` which, if set, resets all uppercase Greek to italic, and then executes it.  But it doesn't actually make the change until `\AtBeginDocument`.  So it might be possible to save the upright Delta for later use before that happens.  Using your suggested name, add this line before `\begin{document}`: `\let\Deltaup\Delta`.  Not tested.  (It's past my time to go to sleep.)

Comment: Dear Barbara, thank you so much for your time and your help.

Comment: Your suggestion worked. Thanks again.

Comment: Dear Barbara, Thanks again for your help.For the lowercase delta to be upright in the same document, I used a similar trick you kindly taught me for the uppercase delta, i.e., I added \let\Deltaup\Delta before \begin{document}. However, it did not work. Would you please let me know if there is a solution for this? Thank you.

Comment: Lowercase Greek is, by default, italic.  So it is necessary to find a font that contains upright Greek set up for math.  `upgreek` is, I believe, compatible with Computer Modern, and `\upbeta` is the form of the name.  It's not clear what typeface is used for Proc. Royal Society A.  The class file has an option `usemathtimes`, but it's not set by default.  If Times *is* used, then the Comprehensive Symbols List shows `\betaup` produced by `txfonts`.  (`txfonts` may be obsolete; I haven't used it myself.  `newtxmath` seems to be its successor.)

Comment: Thank you so much. Your information is very helpful and resolved the problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PRSA document class (`rsproca_new.cls`) contains an option `Capsgreek` that, if set, specifies that all uppercase Greek will be italic.  In the case of `\Delta`, this is set up through `\let\Delta\varDelta`, making it impossible to use `\Delta` in its original meaning.

`Capsgreek` is "executed" (set up) automatically, but not activated until `\AtBeginDocument` making it possible to preserve the original meaning of the capital Greek letters if they are caught before the transformation occurs, i.e., before `AtBeginDocument`.

You have suggested the name `\Deltaup` for the upright delta.  Using this name, you can save the upright Delta for later use by adding this line *before* `\begin{document}`:

```
\let\Deltaup\Delta
```

The same mechanism can be used to "preserve" the other uppercase Greek letters that are normally defined, remembering that the Greek caps that have the same shape as Latin uppercase letters do not have defined TeX command names.